# Error in URL connection of PostGIS Raster community module plugin in GeoServer

Tags: raster, postgis, geoserver, postgresql, postgis-raster

I have a raster named MODIS_All_India_NDVI_2001_01_01.tif in the database named agro_dss in
PostGIS, in the public.modis_all_india_ndvi_2001_01_01 table.

[image: fig 1]

The import was done using:

```
raster2pgsql -s 4326 -I -C -M D:\Advisory\Raster\MODIS_All_India_NDVI_2001_01_01.tif -F -t auto public.MODIS_All_India_NDVI_2001_01_01 | psql -U postgres -d agro_dss -h localhost -p 5432
```

as I am using

```
GeoServer Version
2.18.1
Git Revision
95cf8a329b0b51b69e1ea8d833bcb8b2ccc9b2be
Build Date
19-Nov-2020 15:33
GeoTools Version
24.1 (rev 7d309a25d2f0c857fd67c09b0d5392432d77fc4c)
GeoWebCache Version
1.18.1 (rev 08dd9de02426482f542b003f3bf381497939eb04/08dd9de02426482f542b003f3bf381497939eb04)
```

so I downloaded and installed the compatible version of GeoServer PGRaster community module ([geoserver-2.18-SNAPSHOT-pgraster-plugin.zip](https://build.geoserver.org/geoserver/2.18.x/community-latest/))

I unzipped the files named

1. gs-pgraster-2.18-SNAPSHOT.jar
2. gt-imagemosaic-jdbc-24-SNAPSHOT.jar

in the directory `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib`
then added the path of raster2pgsql.exe in JAVA_OPTS of Tomcat configuration .exe as

```
-DRASTER2PGSQL_PATH=C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin
```

I then restarted the Tomcat server, and it worked fine as I was able to see the **ImageMosaicJDBC - Image mosaicking/pyramidal jdbc plugin**
in new Raster Data Sources

[image: fig 2]

to Configure ImageMosaicJDBC store, I added these 3 files in the directory `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data`

1st file `connect.pgraster.xml.inc`

```
<connect>
   <dstype value="DBCP"/>
   <username value="postgres"/>
   <password value="mypassword"/>
   <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/agro_dss"/>
   <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
   <maxActive value="10"/>
   <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>
```

2nd file `mapping.pgraster.xml.inc`

```
<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
 <mapping>
      <masterTable name="mosaic" >
              <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
              <maxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
              <maxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
              <minXAttribute name="minX"/>
              <minYAttribute name="minY"/>
              <resXAttribute name="resX"/>
              <resYAttribute name="resY"/>
              <tileTableNameAtribute name="tiletable" />
      </masterTable>
      <tileTable>
              <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
      </tileTable>
</mapping>
```

3rd file `mosaicpgraster.pgraster.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
      <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
      <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.pgraster.xml.inc">
]>

<config version="1.0">
      <coverageName name="mosaicpgraster"/>
      <coordsys name="EPSG:4326"/>
      <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
      <axisOrder ignore="false"/>
      &mapping;
      &connect;
</config>
```

after this
1 added an additional table in agro_dss database to store mosaic metadata.

```
CREATE TABLE public.mosaic (
    name character varying(254) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    tiletable character varying(254) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    minx double precision,
    miny double precision,
    maxx double precision,
    maxy double precision,
    resx double precision,
    resy double precision,
    CONSTRAINT mosaic_pkey PRIMARY KEY (name, tiletable)
);
```

then added the raster to this mosaic metadata table, and assigned the name mosaicpgraster:

```
insert into mosaic (name,tiletable) values ('mosaicpgraster','modis_all_india_ndvi_2001_01_01 table');
```

Finally, as I am creating new database in **ImageMosaicJDBC store**, I am getting the error while connecting the **mosaicpgraster.pgraster.xml** file in **URL**

This file is located in `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geoserver\data` for which, I have tried to parse the URL as

```
file:data/mosaicpgraster.pgraster.xml
```

[image: error 1]

and further as

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/data/mosaicpgraster.pgraster.xml
```

but I am getting errors both ways,
[image: error 2]

**How to rectify it?**

Answer (score 0):

Use URL as:
file:mosaicpgraster.pgraster.xml.xml